# Hard disk Start and End Calculations (closed)

Tags: debian, disk, parted

I am using the common Linux **Parted** command which is used to manipulate the partition table, but there is a problem. i was trying to create a new partition using the **mkpart** option. While i was doing this it asked for the partition **start** and **end**.

Now i believe i know what the **start** and **end** is, the start and end is esentially the starting and the ending of the partition on the disk or in other words the destination from the start and ending.

So as this happend i dont know how to calculate the start and ending for a new partition, so my question is:

- How do i calculate the **start** and **end?**

Comment: If this is the only partition on this disk then the start will be 1 and the end will be whatever the rest of the space is in either bytes, sectors, or as a percentage of remaining space. [Check out the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html) for more information. If you are having issues calculating this update your post with the output of `lsblk` and/or `parted -l`

Comment: i only have 1 primary partition on my disk which is sda1 (boot) partition, what will be the start and end in that case, and how will i calculate it?

Comment: The start of new partition can be 1 unit more than the end of the previous partition (Boot). The end will be up to the total capacity of the drive unless you desire to leave some unformatted space to be used in the future or you need more than 1 partition. So this space will be however much you need up to the total capacity. So if you have a drive that is 65536000000 (units in bytes or roughly 64 GB) and the 1st partition is 1 to 1024000000 units in bytes the 2nd partition could be 1024001000 to 95% or 62259200000 roughly. Honestly I just use gparted but we need the output of parted -l to help

Comment: i see thanks so much for the help, so i got another question: so if i had a disk with lets say a total of 700GB and 300GB was for the primary boot and i wanted another 300GB partition for a dual boot but i wanted the last 100GB to be free and unallocated. so firstly lets assume the first boot partition starts at 1 and ends 300000MB (300000 MB is 300GB) and i wanted to create the other 300GB partition, would i start at 300001 MB? if this is true please tell me also when do i know when i should end it in order to get the full 300GB partiton i require?

Comment: Honestly I just use gparted, or whatever the debian installer uses, it shows a graphical representation of what you are trying to do so you have less of a chance to make a mistake and you really do not have to think about it like this. Please read over the manual for parted and look up a guide for partitioning. Your intuition regarding this is correct. But honestly when it comes to dual boots I have had the most success with using separate disks for each os. Barring that an even safer option is to only use the OS you are most familiar with and use the other as a VM.

Comment: Hm i see, ok man thanks very much i really appreciate it

Comment: Last question, i know what to write for the start but when do i know when to end? Or in other words how do i calculate the end value

Comment: The end value is how much space you want so if you need 30gb of space the partition would be the start plus 30gb

Comment: Ah ok i see thanks for the help kind sir :)